# Eclipse Expressions debug panel cuts arrays off at 31 elements

Tags: php, eclipse, xdebug, eclipse-luna

[image: Eclipse Screen Cap]

When trying to expand arrays in the expression watch panel of eclipse, only the first 0...30 elements expand. The rest will just make the expand button disappear. Has anyone faced this issue and fixed it?

This is not a problem in the cluttered variable view, only in the Expression watch view. My workaround is to watch an array slice, which is very tedious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Within Eclipse go to Window -> Preferences -> 
PHP -> Debug -> Installed Debuggers. Highlight XDebug and click 
"Configure". Within the window that pops up you can see the array depth 
and the max children. Setting those values higher will give you more 
data back about your variables.

Answer (score -1):

In Aptana Studio 3, the option is at Window->Preferences->Aptana Studio->Editors->PHP->Debug